# Subnets non-mesh Wi-Fi on mesh Wi-Fi environment

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, subnet

**Situation**

I am living in a shared house where the Internet is provided by the owner. He installed Wi-Fi Access Points in different places of the house and an Internet port in each room. I want to create a subnetwork in my room, to be able to access easily my other equipments and if I do a misconfiguration and the network falls, not the entire network falls (as it happened at the beginning). So the goal is to create an "isolated" subnet, which is still connected to the Internet, and not to extend the range of the already existing network.

To simplify the explanation I will call the house owner my *ISP*, the subnetwork in my room the *LAN,* the entire house's network the *WAN* and finally everything outside the house's network such as websites, etc. the "*Internet Side*". I know that is not very accurate, but it is to simplify my explanation.

On a first time, I created my sub-network and I configured my router to provide a Wi-Fi access as a totally separate name from the WAN's Wi-Fi name so I can work with my other computer without an Ethernet cable running in all my room to my bed. Everything worked perfectly at the beginning.

**Problem**

At a certain point, my router as been disconnected to the Internet connection. I was able to ping the other equipments on the LAN and on the WAN but nothing on the Internet Side. As I identified with a trace-route that the problem was a kind of firewall blockage, I asked my ISP what was the problem.

From what he was able to explain, I understood that as the WAN's Wi-Fi is a mesh Wi-Fi and as the Wi-Fi created by my router is not, the WAN's router detected mine as a potentially malicious and disconnected it from the Internet access.

When my ISP unlocked the access, it worked again perfectly, but the WAN's router locked the access once again. This time, I killed the Wi-Fi access point and kept the LAN's Ethernet access and as far as I write these lines it hasn't been disconnected (at least 36 hours of uptime against maximum 6 hours before being disconnected when my router's Wi-Fi was activated).

So the problem seems to be confirmed that it has a link to the non-mesh Wi-Fi of my subnetwork on a mesh Wi-Fi network environment.

Topology of the network to clarify the situation
[image: Topology of the network to clarify the situation]

**Question**

So my question is: Is there a way to configure correctly my router, so I can have a Wi-Fi access to my LAN without being disconnected by the WAN's router? Is there an option to select as disabling or enabling a certain service?

When I look on forums, the only things that I can find are the pro and cons of mesh Wi-Fi and I can't find the ways to configure routers and if it is possible to make the cohabitation between mesh and non-mesh Wi-Fi possible.

If it can help for the answer, the router is a Netgear WNDR3700 v1. It runs with its original OS, but I can flash it to DD-WRT (or any other) if needed. And the WAN's router is an EERO.

**TLDR**
*Is there a way to make cohabitate a subnetwork's non-mesh Wi-Fi with a network's Wi-Fi that is mesh?*

Comment: The ISP's explanation doesn't make sense to me. Why would a residential ISP-provided router *care* about this? People do it a lot. Why would "mesh" have any relevance? Why would it be different for Wi-Fi over Ethernet? They *may* be right if it's something deliberately done by their device, but I'm leaning towards "the support person made some shit up on the spot".

Comment: I am living in a small student house, so I think that my ISP built a homemade infrastructure, and I really don't understand his justification. Can it be a brand specific behavior?

Comment: Just to make sure we mean the same thing with words: "subnet" is NOT the same things as a wireless network running "under" another wireless network. It may be helpful to find a different term that more clearly conveys that you are not talking about a network subnet, regarding IP addressing.

Comment: I confirm that I speak about a subnet in term of IP. And I would like that the LAN's router which is producing this subnet provides a connection by Ethernet but also wireless by Wi-Fi (which is causing the problem).

Comment: `the WAN's router detected mine as a potentially malicious and disconnected it from the Internet access` AFAIK that isn't even possible. Even say your WiFi is unencrypted, and the WAN router would literally bother to capture WiFi traffics over the air and be able to see the AP's MAC and know your private IP subnet, the traffics that goes out of the WAN port of your router would have a different MAC and its WAN IP being source IP because of source NAT. (With that said, I heard that there are ways to detect (guess?) whether an attached LAN host is / is working as a router.)

Comment: I contacted the WAN's router and Access Point constructor (Eero) to have a better understanding of the situation... I hope that they will answer, even if that it means opening the network to another brand. In the meantime, if someone has an idea, I take any of them.